# variable value is not changing in a map function paired with mongoose querys

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am working on a mern project where i need to create an agenda that contains an attribute as array of appointments types.

in the nodejs api i am declaring a var typeRefs = [];
if a type is present in the types model i insert its ref in the previous array else i create the type and insert the new type ref in the previous array, finally i create the agenda doc based on the typeRefs array, but the array is empty outside the map function scope , inside the map function scope i can see the array values changing.

//agenda model

```
const agendaSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    types: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Type" }],
    establishment: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Establishment",
    },
    template: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Template" },
    isActive: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

var Agenda = mongoose.model("Agenda", agendaSchema);

export default Agenda;
```

// types model

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const typeSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    duration: Number,
    color: String,
    online: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    establishment: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Establishment",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

var Type = mongoose.model("Type", typeSchema);

export default Type;
```

// api function for agenda creation

```
export const add = async (req, res) => {
  var data = req.body;
  try {
    var typesRefs = [];
    data.types.map((type) => {
      Type.find({ name: type.text.toUpperCase() }, (err, res) => {
        if (res.length === 0) {
          const newType = new Type({
            name: type.text.toUpperCase(),
            establishment: data.establishment,
          });
          newType.save();
          typesRefs = [...typesRefs, newType._id];
        } else {
          typesRefs = [...typesRefs, type._id];
        }
      });
    });

    console.log(typesRefs);
    await Agenda.create({ ...data, types: typesRefs });

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Agenda created successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(401).json({ message: "An error occured !" });
  }
};
```

Comment: You're not waiting for the asynchronous result of those `Type.find(...)` calls.

Comment: If you ignore the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to use a for loop instead of map function.

```
export const add = async (req, res) => {
  var data = req.body;
  var typeRefs = [];
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.types.length; i++) {
      const typeExist = await Type.find({
        name: data.types[i].text.toUpperCase(),
      });
      if (typeExist.length === 0) {
        const newType = await Type.create({
          name: data.types[i].text.toUpperCase(),
          establishment: data.establishment,
        });
        typeRefs = [...typeRefs, newType._id];
      } else {
        typeRefs = [...typeRefs, data.types[i]._id];
      }
    }

    console.log(typeRefs);
    await Agenda.create({ ...data, types: typeRefs });

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Agenda created successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(401).json({ message: "An error occured !" });
  }
};
```